# kubernetes cluster adding windows node

Tags: windows, docker, kubernetes, cni

Windows server 2019 - os build 1809 - Fully updated
Kubernetes cluster creation with kubespray and add windows with this https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/adding-windows-nodes/

Node added but when kube-flannel pod runs, it throws below error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vbE2.png)

```
WARNING: The names of some imported commands from the module 'hns' include unapproved verbs that might make them less
discoverable. To find the commands with unapproved verbs, run the Import-Module command again with the Verbose
parameter. For a list of approved verbs, type Get-Verb.
FATA[2021-07-20T14:36:35-07:00] rpc error: code = Internal desc = could not create IP forward entry: The object already exists.
I0720 14:36:36.635659    9876 main.go:518] Determining IP address of default interface
I0720 14:36:38.070746    9876 main.go:531] Using interface with name vEthernet (Ethernet) 2 and address 192.168.10.151
I0720 14:36:38.070746    9876 main.go:548] Defaulting external address to interface address (192.168.10.151)
E0720 14:36:39.091376    9876 main.go:243] Failed to create SubnetManager: error retrieving pod spec for 'kube-system/kube-flannel-ds-windows-amd64-g6nn9': Get "https://127.0.0.1:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/kube-flannel-ds-windows-amd64-g6nn9": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

Docker version 20.10.6
I have tried with multiple docker ee version that is 19.3 or 18.09

Also verified service account exist as it is the known issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have tried different docker version, however haven't tried different `windows kube-proxy` ones, especially  1.20.0 instead of 1.21.0 that you have installed as per provided manual.

```
curl -L https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/sig-windows-tools/releases/latest/download/kube-proxy.yml | sed 's/VERSION/v1.20.0/g' | kubectl apply -f -
```

[Kube-Proxy-Windows CrashLoopBackOff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67369225/kube-proxy-windows-crashloopbackoff). CHeck also EDIT1 that fix flannel issue.